# How to *Lower* an Underground Pop-Up Impact Sprinkler Head

Tags: irrigation

I have replaced a broken Orbit Satellite Sprinkler head with an Orbit Satellite II sprinkler head.
[image]

In their wisdom, Orbit has made the Satellite II about a half to a full inch longer than its predecessor, meaning I have to lower it or have it eaten by a lawnmower.

How can I do this? It's mounted via the bottom from a supply line that has a 90 degree joint in it. It would be very easy to raise, which is why I've found at least countless guides online for raising a sprinkler head that is too low.

Are there any tips or tricks someone can give me so I can lower it? I'm trying to avoid digging up my entire lawn just to get it an inch lower. Since it's near the corner of my lawn I was hoping to just bump up the grass in the area by under-filling it.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with this does not involve digging up your whole lawn. You just need to dig up the area around the sprinkler head that needs to be lowered.

Once you dig out the area cut off the existing 90 degree elbow that is in there feeding up. Cut on the horizontal pipe about 5 to 6" from the existing elbow.

Next you would install two 45 degree fittings in sequence using a short piece of PVC pipe between them and then another piece to get back to horizontal again. This horizontal run is then terminated with a new 90 degree elbow to face up to accept the sprinkler head.

Dry fit all the parts before gluing them all together. This is important because you will need to rotate the double 45 degree fittings to get the needed depth. If you need more depth you just need to extend the length of the pipe added between the two 45 fittings. When everything is fit properly make marks with a felt tip marker at each joint so you get them back in the proper position when you take them back apart to glue them together.

Note that if the sprinkler head is fed from an underground TEE instead of just a 90 degree fitting a similar technique can be used to lower the TEE. It just takes two pairs of the 45 degree fittings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, 2x 45 degree fittings, perfect! I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that takes five minutes and doesn't require cutting into any pipe.

- Buy some 1/2 inch "funny pipe" or flexible black irrigation pipe. You need maybe 1 ft or less.
- Buy 2x 90deg 1/2 inch barbed and threaded connectors to go from your funny pipe to the head and then to your screw into the fitting that is already a part of your main supply line.

Thread 1 90deg threaded/barbed connector to your supply line and the other to your head. Dig the hole however deep you like and connect the two barbed ends with funny pipe. Use a blow torch or heat gun if you need to in order to lightly heat the pipe so it slides on the barbed connectors. Funny pipe is rather flexible. You can angle it down, around in a loop, or however you like to get your drop easily. I'd strongly recommend this flexible pipe configuration anytime you replace a head. You'll have less breaking issues when you run over a head with a lawnmower than if you keep in using the none flexible riser/connectors.

1/2 inch threaded barbed funny pipe Connectors:
[image]